# java string matching from a large text file issue

Tags: java, string, file, text

I would like to implement a task of string matching from a large text file. 
1. replace all the non-alphanumeric characters 
2. count the number of a specific term in the text file. For example, matching term "tom". The matching is not case sensitive.so term "Tom" should me counted. However the term tomorrow should not be counted.

```
code template one:
    try {
           in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
           System.out.println("Not found the text file: "+inputFile);
         }
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        while (( line = in.readLine())!=null){  
               String newline=line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", " ").toLowerCase();
               scanner = new Scanner(newline);
               while (scanner.hasNext()){
                       String term = scanner.next();
                   if (term.equalsIgnoreCase(args[1]))
                   countstr++;
               }
         }
     } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

code template two:
   try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
           System.out.println("Not found the text file: "+inputFile);
         }
   Scanner scanner = null;
   try {
        while (( line = in.readLine())!=null){  
               String newline=line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", " ").toLowerCase();
               String[] strArray=newline.split(" ");//split by blank space
                       for (int =0;i<strArray.length;i++)
                               if (strArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase(args[1]))
                                      countstr++;
               }
         }
     } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

By running the two codes, I get the different results, the Scanner looks like to get the right one.But for the large text file, the Scanner runs much more slower than the latter one. Anyone who can tell me the reason and give a much more efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first approch. You dont need to use two scanner. Scanner with "" is not good choice for the large line.

your line is already Converted to lowercase. So you just need to do lowercase of key outside once . And do equals in loop

Or get the line

```
String key = String.valueOf(".*?\\b" + "Tom".toLowerCase() + "\\b.*?");
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(key);
        word = word.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(word);
        if (m.find()) {
            countstr++;
        }
```

Personally i would choose BufferedReader approach for the large file.

```
String key = String.valueOf(".*?\\b" + args[0].toLowerCase() + "\\b.*?");
         Pattern p = Pattern.compile(key);
         try (final BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(inputFile,
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
                for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
                    // processing the line.
                    line = line.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "");
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
                    if (m.find()) {
                        countstr++;
                    }           
                }
         }
```

Gave Sample in Java 7. Change if required!!